# Tensorflow tfcompile: fail at step 2

Tags: tensorflow-xla

I follow https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tfcompile, and fail at step 2.

What's wrong?

> cschen
>
> ~/git/tensorflow$ bazel build --config=opt //t1:test_graph_tfmatmul
>   ... INFO: Found applicable config definition build:download_clang in
>   file /home/cschen/git/tensorflow/.bazelrc:
>   --crosstool_top=@local_config_download_clang//:toolchain --define=using_clang=true --action_env TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=1 INFO: Found applicable config definition build:opt in file
>   /home/cschen/git/tensorflow/.tf_configure.bazelrc:
>   --copt=-march=native --copt=-Wno-sign-compare --host_copt=-march=native --define with_default_optimizations=true INFO: Build option --cpu has changed, discarding analysis cache.
>   ERROR: Analysis of target '//t1:test_graph_tfmatmul' failed; build
>   aborted: no such package 'tools/target_cpu': BUILD file not found on
>   package path ...

I copy to *t1/BUILD* from step 2 as follows,

> ~/git/tensorflow$ cat t1/BUILD
>   load("//tensorflow/compiler/aot:tfcompile.bzl", "tf_library") ...

The expected result is to generate header file `test_graph_tfmatmul.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version you are using, but on TF1.14, if you `git grep tools/target_cpu`, you will see one result in the file `tensorflow/compiler/aot/tfcompile.bzl`.

In the directory `tools`, there is nothing reminiscent of `target_cpu`, so I think it must be a bug with the `tfcompile.bzl`. The problem disappears for me when I comment out the line referencing tools/target_cpu.